# Multiple stream TCP c#

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying streams 2 things by tcp. My streams will work all the time, one send messages once time at 10 sec. Second stream send 5 time at  second.
On the client side i run this:

```
            new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            Send(stream);
        }).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            Get(stream);
        }).Start();
```

From server side i have something like this:

```
 public void StartListener()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (witchMessages == 0)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                        witchMessages = 1;
                    Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleDeivce3));
                        t.Start(client);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...22");
                        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected!22");
                        Task.Run(() =>
                        {

                            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleDeivce2));
                        t.Start(client);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            server.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I wanted do something like if(firstmessages== true) execute first stream and next time execute second.
But it dont work. When i use task i can run two method, but it dont know when i send something for first and secound and throw exception because first method want read method from secound e.t.c.

Can someone give me tip or link how can i do it?

Is there a better solution then create secound client? or check every time what came?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to send on one connection and receive on another? Normally a client will connect to the server and they talk (send and receive) on that one socket.

Comment: Because one method exchanges different information than the other. I need to send these 2 items independently. On the server side, one method starts every 10sec, the other several times per second regardless of each other. I do not think that a good solution would be to connection it in one method and check every time what came and choose the right answer.

Comment: ok i find solution. I add stream = TcpClient("192.168.3.123"); befor second new Thread(() => in client. I create new stream and it work